# mp3 file path not playing from ArrayList? FileNotFoundException in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, path, mp3

I am trying to create an MP3 player (console only at the moment) in Java. I have stored a list on track details (Name, Artist, Length, Genre, Pathway to the track e.g. "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/music.txt") in a text file and have used a method access() in my PlayMusic class to put all track details into separate ArrayLists. I have then inherited this Class into a RockMusic class and created a method to find any Rock music (genre) and then place the track pathway into a FileInputStream to then play the Rock Mp3.The problem is that even though the pathway is being passed correctly I am getting a FileNotFoundException (No such File or Directory). What am I doing wrong.????..please help..my code is below....I have spent hours banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out.

```
public class PlayMusic {

    List<String> trackName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> artist = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> length = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ID = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> IDtrack = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> trackPath = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File("/Users/harvhead/Desktop/music.txt");
    File t = new File("/Users/harvhead/Desktop/musicTracks.txt");


public void access() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    try {
```

// reading each line of text and placing the 1st 2nd 3rd 4th element into different String Arraylist

```
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(",");

            String trackN = details[0];
            String artistN = details[1];

            String trackLength = details[2];
            String genreN = details[3];
            String IDN = details[4];

            String Pathtrack = details[5];

            trackName.add(trackN);

            artist.add(artistN);
            length.add(trackLength);
            genre.add(genreN);
            ID.add(IDN);

            trackPath.add(Pathtrack);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Playlist Error");
    }

    if (trackName.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Arraylist is Empty");

    } else {
        System.out.println("ArrayList is not Empty");
    }
}
```

Below is the method from my RockMusic Class:

```
public void rockPlayMusic() throws FileNotFoundException {

    // call the access method (from PlayMusic Class) to create arraylists from txt file

    access();

    // finding Rock tracks and then trying to play them

    for (int x = 0; x < genre.size(); x++) {
        if (genre.get(x).contains("Rock")) {

            try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(trackPath.get(x));
                System.out.println(trackPath.get(x));
                Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);

                playMP3.play();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Below is my main:

```
package musicapp;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class MusicApp {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    rockMusic rock = new rockMusic();

    rock.rockPlayMusic();
}
```

}

Below is my error in the console:

```
ArrayList is not Empty
java.io.FileNotFoundException:   "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3" (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/Slave To The Wage.mp3" (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/Six Shooter.mp3" (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/Bones.mp3" (No such file or directory)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is the code for passing the file path manually into the FileInputStream and it plays the mp3 (I also got it to print the file path in the console).

```
public void manualPlayTest(){

    try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3");
                System.out.println("/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3");
                Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);

                playMP3.play();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }



}
```

Hardcoded path into rockPlayMusic method and this works fine.

```
public void rockPlayMusic() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // call the access method (from PlayMusic Class) to create arraylists from txt file

    access();
    // finding Rock tracks and then trying to play them
    for (int x = 0; x < genre.size(); x++) {
        if (genre.get(x).contains("Rock")) {

            try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3");
                System.out.println(trackPath.get(x));
                Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);

                playMP3.play();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[console output from hardcoded path in rockMusicPLay() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9feuB.png)

Comment: Have you checked permissions on that file or directory?

Comment: The mp3's play fine when I pass the file path in manually to the FileInputStream (not through the arrayList) so I assumed the permissions were ok....just checked the file and it says read and write permissions for harvhead (me) and read permissions for everyone else....this should be ok shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you include your code snippit in the post for when you manually pass the path and it works?

Comment: I've added a test piece of code which passes the file path manually without using the arraylist element. It works perfectly and plays the mp3 and prints the file path to the console.....I appreciate the time you're giving this.

Comment: Sure thing! Try this, I'm guessing it won't work but still worth checking. In your application code that isn't working, have you tried hardcording a path just like your test? Just to see if that works similar to your test. I know it isn't the solution, I'm just trying to better diagnose the issue. Curious if that works,

Comment: If I hardcode the path into the FileStreamInput of the rockPlayMusic method it works fine (see new code I've added)...the problem seems to be something do with the state of the path when it is called from the ArrayList although it appears fine as evidence from the sout.println....I've added a screenshot of the console after running this code

Comment: For your text file you're splitting into an arroy, can you update it with absolute files paths instead of the relative ones? I.e., instead of "/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3" put "c:/Users/harvhead/Desktop/San Tropez.mp3".

Comment: I'm using a Mac so there is no C drive and from what I've read the /Users path is the absolute path...I've just tested out putting some random mp3 file paths into a test arrayList and when I use the get method for the ArrayList the paths are found and the music plays

Comment: I'm going to continue testing things but any tips will be greatly appreciated...I'm suspecting that the problem is to do with the access method being in a different class despite inheriting it and there being no compile errors

Comment: holy moly...I've solved it....really irritating but thats code for you...anyway...basically the path wan't working because of the quotation marks..I removed them from the text file and boom it works....it must be the ArrayList parsing them as Strings and therefore not needing the quotation marks or something like that anyway......I am soooooooo happy